# Changing the type of an App to Universal App later in App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, universal-binaries

Can I change the type of an submitted App in the App Store later? Initially I want to submit an iPhone only App, but later there might be an Universal App as well to support the iPad. Can this be submitted as an update to the existing App? So can the type of an App changed later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Xcode has built-in support for targeting specific devices with your app. It's as simple as selecting the target device from a drop-down list.

This could enable you to create an initial version that targets either iPhone or iPad, and then later switch to Universal and submit it as a new version. The App Store will then automatically recognize that the new version of the app is Universal, and you would need to add additional screenshots, etc. for the new devices.

Comment: How about downgrading a Universal type app to an iPhone app only?

Comment: According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410636/change-targeted-device-family-on-existing-iphone-ipad-app) (and [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1623/_index.html)), you cannot take away support for a device that you previously supported.  I.e. you cannot downgrade from a Universal app to an iPhone-only app.