# Transfer Company Apple Developer membership to Individual on iTunes App Store without repaying

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, developer-program

Basically doing the complete reverse as [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323868/transfer-individual-apple-developer-membership-to-company-on-itunes-app-store-wi).

I'm looking to dissolve my company and transfer my company's Apple Developer to myself i.e. individual (or to another newly incorporated entity). Is that even possible?

Has anyone managed such a transfer of Apple Developer membership?

p.s. I've just renewed the Developer membership a few weeks ago and now my co-founder and I have come to the conclusion we should dissolve our incorporation and in that case I will take ownership of the app. So the best case scenario is that I can somehow transfer the company Apple Developer membership to myself (Individual) without repaying.

Comment: Please let me know how this goes, I'm looking to do the same

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the transformation of an individual account to an organization account, there's no tool for initiating such a transformation on Apple's web site.

The only way to know if Apple will allow your to change your account type is to contact their support for clarification.

Note that it is always possible to transfer the app from the organization to a personal account for you by simply opening a new personal account (and thus paying again), and then using the ordinary tools for transferring apps between accounts.